# Cardinality of the set of all roots of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I found this to be an interesting question.

Define $S$ = {$n^{1/k}|n, k \in \Bbb N$}.

Now clearly $\Bbb N \subset S$ $\to |S|\ge |\Bbb N|$.

Let $T$ = {$\frac{1}{k}$|$k\in \Bbb N$}.

Define $f:T \to \Bbb N$ by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Then |$T$| = |$\Bbb N$|.

Now we use the fact that |$A^{B}$| = |$A$|$^{|B|}$.

I.e., |$S$| = $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$.

Now, how do we go forward? [Note: $0$ is not included in $\Bbb N$ here].

Comment: Aleph-Null^Aleph_null is the same as 2^alephnull. This is the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: @Alephnull how is that the case?

Comment: @It is well known.

Comment: Hint: compare this to the cardinality of the rationals.

Comment: Your $S$ is a subset of the set of [algebraic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) which is countable, see for example [Proving the countability of algebraic numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/50658).

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is flawed. We are not choosing the functions from one set to the other but merely pairs including one from either set (and this overcounts). Thus you want alephnull x alephnull is alephnull. The overcounting doesn't hurt because it clearly has a subset of size alephnull.

Comment: Relevant username :)

Comment: @wojowu that's what I was thinking.  :D